# Problem with PSR-4 Autoloader using composer

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload

I have this directories structure:

```
  src
   - PrintXMLInfo.php
   - PrintListInfo.php
   - PrintInformation.php

  vendor

  main.php

  composer.json
```

Now in composer.json I declared this psr-4 autoload:

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "TemplateMethod\\": "src/"
    }
}
```

And in the abstract class PrintInformation I put:

```
namespace TemplateMethod;

abstract class PrintInformation
```

And Extended it in PrintXMLInfo and PrintListInfo

```
namespace TemplateMethod;

use TemplateMethod\PrintInformation;

class PrintXMLInfo extends PrintInformation
```

The same in PrintListInfo.

The problem is "use TemplateMethod\PrintInformation";

I'm in the same namespace of PrintInformation, but if I write:

```
use PrintInformation;
```

i get an error of class not found:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PrintInformation' not found in /home/vagrant/shared/template_method/src/PrintXMLInfo.php on line 6
```

I can't get where I'm wrong, if parent and child class are in the same namespace shouldn't I be able to call them without namespace prefix in use, right?

Comment: When classes are in the same namespace, you don't need a `use` statement

Comment: Thanks I forget this.

Comment: Oh If I got well it tried to load .../src/src/... when I pur use, is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking there but just remember that `use` statements do not use relative paths